# SQL Server 2012 LIKE expression pattern

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on an assignment that requires that I add a constraint that makes sure that all values in a column are purely numerical. Im starting with

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD CONSTRAINT ck_name CHECK (col_name LIKE 'pattern');
```

The problem is that the values can vary in length. I've been doing a lot of reading but i cant figure out a pattern that will limit it to numbers but still let it vary in length. I know in MySQL you can do '[0-9]*', but this doesn't work on SQL Server. Can anyone point me in the direction of an equivalent or confirm that it cant happen/i am approaching it wrong?

Edit: I have to use a constraint, per the assignment requirements.

Comment: If you want that column was numerical just make it of numerical type.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736630/sql-constraint-minvalue-maxvalue

Comment: Hamlet, I have to use a constraint, per the assignment requirements.

Answer (score 0):

```
   ADD CONSTRAINT ck_name CHECK (TRY_PARSE(col_name AS int) IS NOT NULL);
```

Haven't tried this but might work?

Comment: This defeats the point of the assignment. It has to be a CHECK constraint. Thanks though!

Comment: @southerneagle16 I meant to add it in the check constraint. see answer again. TRY_PARSE could also be useful. It just has to be a valid expression I think. i.e. returns true\false

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD CONSTRAINT ck_name CHECK (ISNUMERIC(col_name)<>0);
```

(OR) something like this

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD CONSTRAINT ck_name 
CHECK (not col_name like '%[^0-9]%');
```