# Regular expression to validate multiple ranges of numbers

Tags: java, regex, validation

I am trying to validate numbers which are allowed to belong to multiple ranges. e.g.:

***A number x is valid if it lies between 150-200, or 700-750***

Basically I want to store these restrictions in a database, so I thought storing them as regexes would be a nice way of handling this problem.

I am new to regular expressions, so am not being able to come up with one for the above validation.

Comment: Regex just isn't *a nice way of handling this problem*... you're using a DBMS, stick to the tools already in the DB... regex is slow. If you're using SQL, check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736630/sql-constraint-minvalue-maxvalue ... otherwise, tag your DBMS

Comment: @Mariano being slow may not be main problem. If ranges will be more complex creating and maintaining regex will be nightmare: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20793792/1393766

Comment: @Pshemo I know, I've gone that way just for fun. Of course, you can always [cheat](http://utilitymill.com/utility/Regex_For_Range)

Comment: @Mariano How do you think I create regex for that answer ;) (too bad that site is off-line now).

Comment: @Pshemo ah, I just saw the link in your post. :-)

Answer (score 2):

**Solution:**

```
1[5-9][0-9]|200|7[0-4][0-9]|750
```

**Explanation:**

Since you have a very well defined ranges, the regex is fairly simple.

It can be broken up into two parts:

1. 150 **through** 199 **OR** 200
2. 700 **through** 749 **OR** 750

So, put together the regex will read as

((150 **through** 199 **OR** 200) **OR** (700 **through** 749 **OR** 750))

Your first number is 150, so we will have to match a '1' for the first digit followed by the range for the second digit which could be 5 though 9 (you don't want anything less that 150, so 4 and less are out) and also followed by the range for the third digit which could be anything from 0 to 9.  This captures all numbers from 150 to 199.

The last number in the first range is 200, so we can just look for that.  It is too different from the rest of the possibilities in the range, thus it is easier to look for specifically for it instead of trying to think of a complex way of including it in a regex range.

The second range follows the same patten but with different numbers. Again, we are looking for most of the numbers by using the regex range and looking for the last number, 750, specifically since it is too different -- has a number 5 in the middle.  If we include 5 in the middle regex range, it will go up to 759, which is outside of the scope.

Finally, **OR** both parts and the regex is ready.

Adjust for your input.  You may need to surround it with ^ and $ for the beginning and the end of the line or if your input has other text surrounding the number in question, expand your regex to deal with it appropriately.

Comment: While this regex may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: You may want to anchor it to `^` and `$` to avoid matching other numbers

Comment: @JAL Good point.  The explanation is now provided in the answer.

Comment: @Mariano You are assuming the number is on its own line.  I deliberately stayed away from surrounding the regex with anything.  The answer responds to shiladitya's specific question.  He didn't provide any more specifics, so assumptions about his input could make the answer unnecessarily complicated and confusing.

Comment: @keda Any anchors should suffice, either line, boundary or lookarounds, in order to avoid the undesired result: 'why is it matching the subject `"1200"`'. You did clarify that point with your last edit though.