# oracle sql column value from .. to

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints

I can't find anything in internet about setting range of column values. For example I want to add column "grade" which is 1 to 6 how can I validate this?

Comment: you can use check constraints to make sure values in a column are in a certain range or set of values. Or you could have a table of acceptable answers and use a foreign key to join the main table to that lookup table.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL constraint minvalue / maxvalue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736630/sql-constraint-minvalue-maxvalue)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a check constraint to your table. e.g:

```
ALTER TABLE your_table
ADD CONSTRAINT check_grade
  CHECK (grade between 1 and 6);
```

Comment: Great! Please don't forget to mark the answer as correct.